# Android layout button lower than others in horizontal linearlayout

Tags: android, xml, button, layout, margin

for some reason the button on the right comes out lower. I have attempted to edit the different parts, am I missing a margin difference or is it because of space fitting in. It is simply a linear layout horizontal with a textview, edit text and button.

[Screenshot of the XML design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osJSH.png)
Please check the picture in the link

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtv_ISBN"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="60dip"
            android:minWidth="80dip"
            android:text="@string/isbn"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_ISBN"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="@color/White"
            android:hint="@string/barcode_hint"
            android:inputType="textPassword|number"
            android:minHeight="60dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_pallet_isbn_clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:minHeight="60dip"
            android:minWidth="100dip"
            android:text="@string/clear"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>!
```

Comment: where is screenshot ? I don't see any iimage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

to your linear layout

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_pallet_isbn_clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:minHeight="60dip"
        android:minWidth="100dip"
        android:singleLine="true"   <------that
        android:text="@string/clear"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: This also works, but I really wanted the answer below. But thanks.